# How can I return data to a $.get call from an Arduino server?

Tags: http, get, arduino, esp8266

I've got an Arduino Leonardo with a ESP8266 WiFi module, and I'm turning the onboard LED (pin 13) on and off from a browser via jQuery's `$.get()`. It works, but now I want to return data to this get call. How can I do it? I know that I have to codify it in plain text and return it from the "server", but no idea how.

This is my JavaScript/jQuery line:

```js
function setLEDstat(setLED){
    $.get("http://192.168.0.222:12345/", {LED:setLED}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And this is my Arduino's response so far:

```c++
void switchLED(){
  int connectionId = Serial1.parseInt();
  Serial1.find("LED=");
  int setLED = Serial1.parseInt();
  Serial.println("Conn: " + String(connectionId) + ", LED: " + String(setLED));
  if (setLED == 1){
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("AT+CIPSEND=" + String(connectionId) + ",38");
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial1.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=" + String(connectionId));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to obtain a response by means of HTTP headers (you learn something new everyday!!). The code for my Arduino's function now goes like so:

```cpp
void switchLED(){
  int connectionId = Serial1.parseInt();
  Serial1.find("LED=");
  int setLED = Serial1.parseInt();
  Serial.println("Conn: " + String(connectionId) + ", LED: " + String(setLED));
  if (setLED == 1){
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    nanoSerial.println("LED=1");
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    nanoSerial.println("LED=0");
  }
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("AT+CIPSEND=" + String(connectionId) + ",145");
  delay(100);
  Serial1.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  Serial1.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  Serial1.println("Content-Length:05");
  Serial1.println("Connection: close");
  Serial1.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  Serial1.println("");
  Serial1.println("LED=" + String(setLED));
  delay(500);
  Serial1.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=" + String(connectionId));
}
```

I hope this helps anyone in need ;)

Comment: Very cool.  Many APIs return JSON (Content-Type: application/json) which is easily consumed in javascript.  Glad you got it working!